# CSS - Image and label alignment issue in a fixed div

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors

I am trying to settle complete `image` in a `div` container without distorting it and align its `label` just above the `image`. The problem i am facing is if the `image` is smaller the label above it gets distorted. The label should adjust on top of the image with a little bottom padding according to the height of the image. I have used absolute relative between `image` and `div` container. Below code . Please advise.

```
<div class="mx-4" style = "box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative; height: 37rem; width: 30rem;">
      <label  style="white-space:normal !important;
      bottom: 252px;position: absolute;
      background-color:#2a2d34;color:#fff;display: inline-block;
      padding: 0.25em 0.4em;font-size: 125%;font-weight: 700;line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;">{{myfileName}}</label>
      <img style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;" class="imgClass contain" [src]="mySrc"
        alt="Test Image" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for trying to position the label absolutely rather than just have it show at the top of the div followed by the image? And could you explain what the 'distortion' looks like?

Comment: @Haworth - Distortion as in if the image is smaller compared to my div container and i give a fixed height and width . The image will get stretched and look a bit distorted.